# UI thread blocking - All input elements stops working and seems inaccessible when input type range is disabled dynamically in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input, range

When I am trying to disable an input range on my page dynamically, all other input elements on my page stop working in chrome.

Here when I disable `#mySlider`,  `#chkBox` and `#myButton` becomes inaccessible and does not trigger respective functions, even can't able to check the checkbox.

**My chrome version: 31.0.1650.63 m**

**[FIDDLE DEMO >>](http://jsfiddle.net/uLZjE/4/)**

**HTML**

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="mySlider" onChange="checkMove(this)" />

 <input type="checkbox" value="one" id="chkBox" ><br/>
 <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me" onClick="clickCheck();" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function checkMove(elem) {

    var minVal = elem.value;

    if (minVal == 2) {
        elem.disabled = true;
    }
}

function clickCheck() {
    alert("hi")
}
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the range input, disabling it disabled all clicks, even right clicks are disabled. It's the same when using jQuery, and in JSBin, so the only thing left would be the range input causing issues in Chrome.

Comment: Seems like a bug with chrome. report it. http://crbug.com/

Comment: I just filed a bug on this.

Comment: Bug reported here [Bug ID:330485](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=330485)

Comment: As per chrome this issue is fixed now. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=326406

Comment: tried `elem.setAttribute("disabled", true);` ?

Comment: @PrasanthKC I am unable to see your issues or bug when i visite your fiddle.... maybe your issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Since this seems to be a bug with Chrome. You can just hack it by simulating a disabled input, and just change the event to `onmouseup` for this to work

```
/* CSS */

#range {
 position: relative    
}

#range.disabled .cover {
  display: block;
}

#range.disabled input {
 color: rgb(82,82,82);
}

.cover {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: transparent;
 z-index:5;
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
 bottom: 0;
 right:0;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<label id="range">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="mySlider" onmouseup="checkMove(this)">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="one" id="chkBox">
<br/>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me" onClick="clickCheck();" />


// JAVASCRIPT
var range = document.getElementById('range');
function checkMove (elem) {
    var minVal = elem.value;
    console.log(minVal)
    if (minVal >= 2) {
       range.className = 'disabled';
    }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLZjE/7/)

**Edit:**

**2)** another way to hack this, is to avoid disabling it dynamically which is when the error occurs in the first place. have two `range` elements, one `disabled` and one `abled`. hide the disabled element while mirroring the value from the abled element. 
when you want to disable the element, switch the two based on your condition.
 check out [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLZjE/10/), the switch is smoove and not noticeable.

```
<div id="range">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="mySlider" onchange="checkMove(this)">
  <input type="range" disabled min="0" max="5" value="0" id="altSlider">
</div>

// Javascript
var range = document.getElementById('range'),
    alt   = document.getElementById('altSlider');

function checkMove(elem) {
    var minVal = elem.value;
    alt.value = minVal;
    console.log(minVal)
    if (minVal == 2) {
      range.className = 'disabled';
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
#range {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
#range.disabled #altSlider {
  opacity: initial;
}
#range.disabled #mySlider {
 display: none;
}
#altSlider {
 opacity: 0;
}
#mySlider {
 z-index:5;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This trick will not do the job, as this one will disable the slider only if we drop it in specific value. I need something that will disable the slider on move itself.

Comment: do you not want the value to not be greater than 2 ? bc there's plenty of ways to achieve this  depending on what functionality you want

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try jquery selectors to disable it
Html is
     
     `<input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="mySlider" />
     <input type="checkbox" value="one" id="chkBox" ><br/>
      <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me" />`

jquery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#mySlider").change(function(){
       var val = parseInt($(this).val());
       var maxrange= parseInt($(this).attr("max")); 
       if(val>=2){
        $(this).val(2);
        $(this).attr("disabled", "true");   
        } 
       })

        $("#chkBox, #myButton").click(function(){
          alert("It Works!");
        });

     })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the bug has been fixed in chrome... For sometime, but after reviewing the cause and fix implemented for the bug I thought I would provide a workaround if needed.

```
    // Replace the `elem.disabled = true;` with
    setTimeout(function(){ elem.disabled = true; },0);
```

The idea being we let the browser exit it's current event stream and then disable the input element.

The issue was essentially a catch-22, disable the input, and then update the range when the final event comes in, the problem was the element was now disabled and as such would never receive such an event, this left the browser hanging, and it never released the UI.

For more specifics checkout the patch provided in the link in the comment by @PrasanthKC above.